# Setting a footer div to always be at the bottom of the container div regardless of the size of the other elements

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a container div that contains children.

```html
    <div class='wrapper'>
       <div class='content'></div>
       <div class='footer'></div>
    </div>
```

The **content** div can have a dynamic height but the **footer** div needs to always stick to the bottom.

When I try to set wrapper with

```css
    position: relative
```

and the footer child with:

```css
    display: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
```

It only works if I set the height of the wrapper.
Also, when resizing the window, the footer disappears.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior with flexbox without using position? i.e. fixed footer and dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `footer` element. Then you can position your footer as either `absolute` or `fixed` whatever your preference is, and set `bottom: 0;` to get it at the very bottom. In this example, I used `position: fixed;` so it is always in the viewport. I added `200vh` on your `wrapper` just to demonstrate the `footer` always stays put at the bottom of the viewport when scrolling.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class='content'></div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position :fixed;` :

```css
.content {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have it on all my websites and this will stick footer to the bottom of the page. I believe this is the easiest and best solution without  using `position:fixed` for the `#footer`, this way content itself will push `#footer` to bottom, and if there is no content it will still be at the bottom because of `min-height:100vh`. Notice that `120px` is the size of the `#footer` that is why we need to deduct it from `100vh` (of main content).

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:18px;  
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#content {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">this is header</div>
    <div id="content">this is content </div>
    <div id="footer">this is footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can change `position:relative` to `position:fixed` of the `#header` depending on your liking.

Comment: This was a good strategy back when, but flexbox makes it obsolete. No need for manual calculations anymore. P.S. the Tidy button in the snippet editor is your friend. :)

Comment: Not sure, I understood your remark or it is wrong. I believe this the most modern and best solution. I would say "position:fixed" is the old and that was used across all the web since the beginning. You can remove the `min-height` but then the person will not see how it pushes the content, because I do not have any content in my HTML example. And yes, my example relies on flexbox.

Comment: Also I think you wrongly closed this question, since your suggested "duplicates" talk about different things, like `overflow-y:auto` and etc.

Comment: If you're implementing flexbox correctly you don't need to calculate height. Full-height fill is available. That's my point. You also don't need to explicitly position anything. If there's a better duplicate, feel free to raise it. This is not a new subject.